# data replication not happening using RESO spark web API

Tags: php, rets

I am using SPARK Web api to extract RESO data. I am facing an issue with  the data replication. whenever I tried to do the data replication  with a data limit greater than 25 always getting the following error:

{"error":{"code":400,"message":"$top must be an integer between 1 and 25"}}

Can anyone provide any efficient method to get the RESO data with a 1000 records or more per each request using RESO web api?

api request used : https://replication.sparkapi.com/Reso/OData/Property?$top=200.

Comment: I don't believe that this should be 'off topic'.  It's like saying that a question regarding a Google or Amazon API is 'off topic'.

Comment: I am just starting to work with this API as well.  As for your query, I am able to do it using the RESO (deprecated) API and would like to move onto the new RESO Web API.  Let me ask you, I have login credentials to the old API but cannot log into the new API.  Do you specifically need to request Web API password credentials from flexmls?  I want to start using Web API to do queries just like yours above.  I am assuming that you too wish to maintain a local data copy.

Comment: @CarolineBeltran, Hope the following link will help you to understand more on RESO web api http://sparkplatform.com/docs/reso/overview. Here what I actually need is to get a datacount of 1000 or more records in a single API request. Could you please explain how could you able to query the records using the  RESO (deprecated) API.